# Horizontally aligned div-boxes with multiple columns in them

Tags: css

```html
<div style="float:left;padding:10px;border-style:dotted;">
  <div style=" width:45%; -webkit-columns: 100px 2;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     -moz-columns: 100px 2;
    /* Firefox */
     columns: 100px 2;
     display: block;">


    Die Hoffnung steht auf Pappe: "Mama Merkel help us" zum Beispiel, oder: "We want Sweden". Immer, wenn zuletzt irgendwo in Europa Grenzen geschlossen oder Züge gestoppt wurden, sah man Flüchtlinge mit Schildern. Sie wollten weiter: nach Deutschland, nach
    Schweden.


  </div>
</div>

<div style="float:left;padding:10px;border-style:dotted;">div2</div>
<div style="float:left;padding:10px;border-style:dotted;">div3</div>
<div style="float:left;padding:10px;border-style:dotted;">div4</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

I'm trying to align two divs horizontally. In each div I would like to have a flexible multiple column setup to host an unordered list. And I can't get it to work. I tried lots of things. The last one was floating two divs. But as soon as I use the multiple column feature on the content of the first div, the second one will not show it in the same line anymore, no matter what width I set for the first div.
Is there any straight forward way to do what I want?

TL;DR;

- Divs won't float left when there is a multiple-column div nested in the first div. What to do about it?

Comment: show us what youve tried instead of just saying it.

Comment: @Paulie_D... edited my question. Is it better now?

Comment: @Paulie_D... what's a Stack Snippet?

Comment: I think we need an image of what this is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the **width:45%;** if you want to setup a relative width to this div, you will have to setup the width of the parent, else, it take the whole space and make following divs wrap on the second line.

To sum-up, the browser is asking itself: "45% of what?" :)

Answer (score 0):

There you go nice bootstrapping boxes

```css
.bigbox {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 200px;
}

#red-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="red-wrapper">

  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="box"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```